# Algolia/Scout - prevent operations update for certain updates

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, algolia

I'm using Algolia, via Laravel
I'm frequently updating some entries in my database (every 5 mins), e.g. $object->update(['field'=>$new_value])

I would NOT like these changes to trigger updates / "operations" in Algolia, as this field is not relevant for Algolia's search indexing, and it would otherwise generate too many operations (which I'm then billed for).

Other changes should trigger updates in Algolia.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

if you using Laravel scout. you could do something like

```
$modal->unsearchable();

//update the changes

$modal->save()
```

for more info have a look at this https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scout

cheers!